# How do I adjust the position of a UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I need to adjust the vertical position of my UIBarButtonItems. 
I seem to be able to do it for the title just fine but the buttons don't seem to go along with it. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

```
var leftBarButtonItem : UIBarButtonItem?
leftBarButtonItem
    = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.leftBarButtonPressed(_:)))
leftBarButtonItem?.image = UIImage(named: "menu_ic")
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButtonItem
self.navigationController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment(CGFloat(18), for: UIBarMetrics.default)

var rightBarButtonItem : UIBarButtonItem?
rightBarButtonItem
    = UIBarButtonItem(title: "MAP", style: .done, target: self, action: 

#selector(self.rightBarButtonPressed(_:)))
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButtonItem

let height: CGFloat = 60 //sets height of UINavigationBar
let bounds = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height + height)
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment(CGFloat(18), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
```

Comment: I think you should check height/width of UIBarButtons, height/width not same withTitle's height,width.

Comment: You can not change height of navigationBar's frame.